# Return some values in Do-notation - Haskell

Tags: haskell, syntax, monads

I've learnt about `do-notation`. I now want to develop a function, which transforms a list.

I want it to behave like this:

```
λ> transform 42 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 42, 2, 42, 3, 42, 4, 42, 5, 42, 6, 42]
```

My current code is:

```
transform :: a -> [a] -> [a]
transform new_number xs = do x <- xs
                            return x
                            return new_number
```

...and my result is:

```
λ> transform 42 [1, 2, 3]
[42,42,42]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The `do` notation is a syntactic sugar when dealing with monads. As your function has nothing to do with them (well, explicitly), the `do` notation is loosing it's sense here..

Comment: Without `do` it's simply `intersperse 42 [1..6] ++ [42]`. Assuming you care about that last 42.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`return` doesn't work in the same way in Haskell as in imperative languages. Writing two `return`s is pointless here, because the second 'overwrites' the first.

`do`-notation is specifically for dealing with *Monads*, so you have a correct type, but you're using the functions incorrectly. This is how I'd do this:

```
transform :: a -> [a] -> [a]
transform new xs = do
  x <- xs
  [x,new]
```

The reason why this is valid is that I'm ending my expression with something of type `[a]`. You don't necessarily have to use `return`!

Using `do`-notation here is a little confusing, so it may be better to use `concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]`:

```
transform new xs = concatMap (\x -> [x,new]) xs
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to work with the monad List, `return` in the monad list means something like "add the value to the monad context" or in code

```
do x <- xs
   return x
```

is equal to

```
do x <- xs
   [x]
```

Therefore you transform function should be something like

```
tranform :: a -> [a] -> [a]
tranform new_number xs = do x <- xs
                            x: [new_number]
```

This is equivalent to

```
tranform new_number xs = concatMap (:[new_number]) xs
```

The do notation is desugar to

```
xs >>= \x -> x:[new_number]
```

and the binding operator for the monad list is related to concatMap

```
concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

where in this case `m a` is the monad list `[] a`